# How to filter a subquery

Tags: sql

I cant seem to filter the results from the original sub query here. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to find customers who have booked country and rock shows (6, 11). I'm using sql server 2014.

```
SELECT cs.CustomerID 
FROM cs 
(SELECT  ms.StyleName, ms.StyleID, cs.CustomerID
FROM Musical_Styles ms  
INNER JOIN Entertainer_Styles es
ON ms.StyleID  = es.StyleID
INNER JOIN Engagements egs
ON es.EntertainerID = egs.EntertainerID
INNER JOIN Customers cs
ON egs.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
WHERE es.StyleID IN (6, 11))
```

Comment: You can filter a subquery (inside the subquery) just as you can filter ant query. But I fail to see why are using a subquery here

Answer (score 1):

What't the point of using subquery here? I think your data model may need some additional explanation if this doesn't give the result you want.

```
SELECT cs.CustomerID FROM Entertainer_Styles es
INNER JOIN Engagements egs ON es.EntertainerID = egs.EntertainerID
INNER JOIN Customers cs ON egs.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
WHERE es.StyleID IN (6, 11)
```

Comment: I need to understand the concept of filtering sub queries for school. It really doesn’t make sense to me when you can easily just filter everything with the initial sub query.

Comment: That's because your example IMO doesn't need a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off.

```
SELECT cs.CustomerID 
FROM cs
where cs.CustomerID IN
(
    SELECT  cs.CustomerID
    FROM Musical_Styles ms  
    INNER JOIN Entertainer_Styles es
    ON ms.StyleID  = es.StyleID
    INNER JOIN Engagements egs
    ON es.EntertainerID = egs.EntertainerID
    INNER JOIN Customers cs
    ON egs.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
    WHERE es.StyleID IN (6, 11)
)
```

The subquery needs to return a list of ids (as the only column) and by saying where cs.CustomerID IN, you are telling the DBMS to return only those customers whose ID are returned by your subquery.